# Android Debugging not working in Micromax

Tags: android, debugging, cordova, usb-debugging

I am using a Micromax P280 android tablet to test my app using cordova. The app is working fine with genymotion emulator and on my Sony Xperia L. Doesn't know what going wrong with the tablet. As per this http://fileit.in/p/276 link i tried creating 51-android.rules, gave the configuration and restarted the server but still the same output as below.

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

This is the content in 51-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEMS==”usb”, ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bda", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002", MODE=”0666″, OWNER="sneha"
```

Comment: After connecting the device, go to  notification , if it is connected as media device, try changing it with connect with camera, i assume you have enabled the debugging from setting , if you are using it for first time , tap 7 times on build number in setting.